# Delete an Image from ImageView Android

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, android-image

I pull paths of images from a database and create an ImageView and then add it to another ImageView which contains all the images.

```
 LinearLayout linearContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearContainer);
 ImageView imageViews = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
 linearContainer.addView(imageViews);

 for all images
    Bitmap myBitmap = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path), THUMBSIZE,
            THUMBSIZE);

    ImageView image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
    imageViews.addView(image);
    image.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
 end
```

I've written a click listener for the ImageView images which allows it to edit or delete.

```
 imageViews.setOnClickListener() {
     AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(FirstActivity.this);
     // alert has two buttons: edit & delete
     // Edit choice click listener
     // Delete choice click listener
 }
```

I need to know the path in order to delete the record from the database. But I do not get any information about the images added the "imageViews" instance. How do I write the delete click listener? Or is there any other simpler way to establish it?

Comment: I would simply have a property imageId in your model so that each image will have it and then delete it based on that id

Answer (score 0):

set image path in `imageview.setTag(path)`

and retrieve it using

```
imageview.getTag()
```

Comment: I create all the images using imageView and add all of them to imageViews object. 

eg:

`ImageView imageViews;

ImageView imageView1 = "first image";
ImageView imageView2 = "first image";
ImageView imageView3 = "first image";
ImageView imageView4 = "first image";

imageViews.addView(imageView1);
imageViews.addView(imageView2);
imageViews.addView(imageView3);
imageViews.addView(imageView4);

linearLayout.addView(imageViews);

then...

imageViews.setOnClickListener() {
    // if i try to get the tag here it returns null
}`